# NameError: name 'serializers' is not defined

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, python-3.7, active-model-serializers

esal=serializers.FloatField(required=False) NameError: name 'serializers' is not defined

**serializers.py:**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from restapp.models import employee

class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    esal=serializers.FloatField(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model=employee
        fields='__all__'
```

**models.py:**

```
class employee(models.Model):
    eno = models.IntegerField()
    ename = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    esal = models.FloatField()
    eaddr = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Comment: do you have `rest_framework` in your INSTALLED_APPS in settings?

Comment: Yes, I have. `INSTALLED_APPS=['rest_framework']`

Comment: `INSTALLED_APPS=['rest_framework','restapp']`  Have you installed Django Rest Framework? if  not then run this command from the terminal `pip install djangorestframework`

Comment: django restframework is already installed and I have added both est_framework and my application i.e. restapp in INSTALLED_APPS too.

Comment: first of all change you class name to uppercase Employee, and you are using ModelSerializer, why you using     esal=serializers.FloatField(required=False), you class has esal field? Share you Employee model

Comment: I have shared my models.py file in the above.

Comment: Have you managed solving this issue in the end? Facing the same problem, importing the serializer in the proper file etc., no spelling mistake, but still getting this error. Works fine in other serializers though, strange.